# Is Bluetooth communication between iPhones encrypted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gamekit

I have a iPhone app that uses `GameKit` to create a bluetooth connection between two devices. My question is: Is the connection encrypted or do I need to do this manually?

Im using `GKPeerPickerController` with a `GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby` connection type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apple's Developer Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Bluetooth_Basics/BT_Bluetooth_Basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000997-CH214-TP9)

> At the lowest levels of the protocol stack, Bluetooth uses the
>   publicly available cipher algorithm known as SAFER+ to authenticate a
>   device’s identity. The generic-access profile depends on this
>   authentication for its device-pairing process. This process involves
>   creating a special link to create and exchange a link key. Once
>   verified, the link key is used to negotiate an encryption mode the
>   devices will use for their communication.

So, the bluetooth protocol takes care of encrypting the connection.